# DejaVu: free(): invalid next size (normal)

Tags: string, memory, gdb

I have memory leak somewhere and unfortunately the repeated topic which appears on stack overflow didn't help; I don't really understand how this happens since I identified the dubious line from gdb run,

```
void read_data(std::string filename, number_type & parameter, number_type & n_part, number_type & mult){
    std::ifstream infile(filename);
    std::string line; // ERROR LINE 

    size_type counter_numbers = 0;
    size_type counter_lines = 0;
    while (infile)
    {
            std::getline(infile, line); // Read in current line
    .
    .
```

this is where it shows in gdb: free(): invalid next size (normal);
at string definition.  Why would this happen; Any ideas?

thanks, Damir

Running as

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I/users/damir/gsl/include/ -L/users/damir/gsl/lib/ -lgsl -lgslcblas -g -o MultB analysis_mult_b.cpp
```

PS (valgrind output)

```
    valgrind ./MultB arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4

    ==39918== Command: ./MultB arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
    ==39918==
    ==39918== Invalid write of size 8
    ==39918==    at 0x405B55: ??? (in /users/damir/Analysis/MultB)
    ==39918==    by 0x404531: ??? (in /users/damir/Analysis/MultB)
    ==39918==    by 0x5582B44: (below main) (libc-start.c:287)
    ==39918==  Address 0x591e530 is 0 bytes after a block of size 400    alloc'd
    ==39918==    at 0x4C28C20: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==39918==    by 0x512B654: ??? (in /cvmfs/it/compiler/gcc/9.1.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.26)
    ==39918==    by 0x404531: ??? (in /users/damir/Analysis/MultB)
    ==39918==    by 0x5582B44: (below main) (libc-start.c:287)
    ==39918==
    --39918-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
    --39918-- si_code=80;  Faulting address: 0x0;  sp: 0x802b99de0

    valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
    Killed by fatal signal

    host stacktrace:
    ==39918==    at 0x380B1870: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
    ==39918==    by 0x38072784: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
    ==39918==    by 0x38072956: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
    ==39918==    by 0x380F6D27: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
    ==39918==    by 0x38105B60: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)

    sched status:
      running_tid=1

    Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable
    ==39918==    at 0x4C28C20: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==39918==    by 0x512B654: ??? (in /cvmfs/it/compiler/gcc/9.1.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.26)
    ==39918==    by 0x40455D: ??? (in /users/damir/Analysis/MultB)
    ==39918==    by 0x5582B44: (below main) (libc-start.c:287)
```

Output from `readlef -WS ./MultB`:

```
      [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
      [ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000    000000 00      0   0  0
      [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        00000000004002a8 0002a8 00001c 00   A  0   0  1
      [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            00000000004002c4 0002c4 000020 00   A  0   0  4
      [ 3] .hash             HASH            00000000004002e8 0002e8 000334 04   A  5   0  8
      [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        0000000000400620 000620 00005c 00   A  5   0  8
      [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM          0000000000400680 000680 0009f0 18   A  6   1  8
      [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB          0000000000401070 001070 000fe1 00   A  0   0  1
      [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM          0000000000402052 002052 0000d4 02   A  5   0  2
      [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED         0000000000402128 002128 0000c0 00   A  6   4  8
      [ 9] .rela.dyn         RELA            00000000004021e8 0021e8 000048 18   A  5   0  8
      [10] .rela.plt         RELA            0000000000402230 002230 000918 18  AI  5  24  8
      [11] .init             PROGBITS        0000000000403000 003000 00001a 00  AX  0   0  4
      [12] .plt              PROGBITS        0000000000403020 003020 000620 10  AX  0   0 16
      [13] .plt.got          PROGBITS        0000000000403640 003640 000008 08  AX  0   0  8
      [14] .text             PROGBITS        0000000000403650 003650 00a342 00  AX  0   0 16
      [15] .fini             PROGBITS        000000000040d994 00d994 000009 00  AX  0   0  4
      [16] .rodata           PROGBITS        000000000040e000 00e000 000208 00   A  0   0 16
      [17] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS        000000000040e208 00e208 0010cc 00   A  0   0  4
      [18] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        000000000040f2d8 00f2d8 004568 00   A  0   0  8
      [19] .gcc_except_table PROGBITS        0000000000413840 013840 00049c 00   A  0   0  4
      [20] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      0000000000414db0 013db0 000010 08  WA  0   0  8
      [21] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      0000000000414dc0 013dc0 000008 08  WA  0   0  8
      [22] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         0000000000414dc8 013dc8 000230 10  WA  6   0  8
      [23] .got              PROGBITS        0000000000414ff8 013ff8 000008 08  WA  0   0  8
      [24] .got.plt          PROGBITS        0000000000415000 014000 000320 08  WA  0   0  8
      [25] .data             PROGBITS        0000000000415320 014320 000010 00  WA  0   0  8
      [26] .bss              NOBITS          0000000000415340 014330 000138 00  WA  0   0 32
      [27] .comment          PROGBITS        0000000000000000 014330 00002d 01  MS  0   0  1
      [28] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        0000000000000000 01435d 002060 00      0   0  1
      [29] .debug_info       PROGBITS        0000000000000000 0163bd 024611 00      0   0  1
      [30] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        0000000000000000 03a9ce 000e97 00      0   0  1
      [31] .debug_line       PROGBITS        0000000000000000 03b865 005f1d 00      0   0  1
      [32] .debug_str        PROGBITS        0000000000000000 041782 025677 01  MS  0   0  1
      [33] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS        0000000000000000 066df9 002260 00      0   0  1
      [34] .symtab           SYMTAB          0000000000000000 069060 004e60 18     35  57  8
      [35] .strtab           STRTAB          0000000000000000 06dec0 00a877 00      0   0  1
      [36] .shstrtab         STRTAB          0000000000000000 078737 000154 00      0   0  1
```

Comment: Have you tried running your program under valgrind? This error is likely caused by memory corruption at an earlier point.

Comment: Was `readelf -WS` run on `MultB`, or on `Mult`? If the latter, how is it related to `MultB`?

Comment: sorry typo. The same executable of course

Answer (score 1):

> I have memory leak somewhere

You may have, but you have provided no evidence of that.

The problem is subject line: `free(): invalid next size (normal)` is *not* about a memory leak, but rather about heap corruption.

> I don't really understand how this happens

Heap corruption bugs often show up as a crash quite far from where they actually happen. This makes finding them without specialized tools hard.

Fortunately, there *are* specialized tools. Run your program under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org), or with [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer).

**Update:**

```
Invalid write of size 8
    ==39918==    at 0x405B55: ??? (in /users/damir/Analysis/MultB)
    ==39918==    by 0x404531: ??? (in /users/damir/Analysis/MultB)
    ==39918==    by 0x5582B44: (below main) (libc-start.c:287)
    ==39918==  Address 0x591e530 is 0 bytes after a block of size 400    alloc'd
```

That's the heap corruption right there: you are writing 8 bytes past the end of a heap block.

Unfortunately you didn't build `MultB` with debug info, so Valgrind can't tell you where in the source this is happening.

Rebuild your application with `-g` flag, run it under Valgrind again, and fix the bug Valgrind told you about.

Comment: I did valgrind ./a.out doesn't say much: ==32598== Invalid write of size 8

Comment: @damir It's unlikely that this is *all* that valgrind produced. Please edit your question with *complete* valgrind output.

Comment: thanks for your time; Perhaps you can pick something from the whole output (added in p.s. in my question post); Doesn't say much to me

Comment: @damir Yes: I can. Valgrind told you about the heap corruption, and where it's happening. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks; Are you sure..my command is  "g++ -std=c++11 -I/users/damir/gsl/include/ -L/users/damir/gsl/lib/ -lgsl -lgslcblas -g -o MultB analysis_mult_b.cpp"    it doesn't show a different output after valgrind ./MultB...

Comment: "Are you sure ..." Yes, I am. Please update your question with the exact compile command you used, and the output from `readelf -WS ./MultB`. Somehow debug info isn't making it into your binary, or your Vagrind is too old, or something else strange is going on.

Comment: My version is valgrind-3.10.0; I see the newest version 3.15.0